# How can I organize nav menu lists as columns in WordPress?

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, list, menu

Here’s what I am having a hell of a time with. I'm working on a dev site (which is WordPress based) that can be seen [here](http://devwww.interfacett.com/). You see the responsive navigation for the ‘Course Schedule’ section is working good so far on mobile devices. It works how we want it to in the mobile view, but in the desktop view there’s a challenge.

We want the course schedule hover menu to be composed of 3 columns (each one next to each other). ‘Microsoft Training’ and all it's sub-links would be in one column of the hover menu, then the ‘Developer Training’ and ‘Cisco Training’ to be in a middle column’ and the remaining technologies to be in a third and fourth column (see the attached mockup). This would make it so that hover menu for 'Course Schedule' is wide, but it wouldn't have one huge long list.

Now, I know how to do this to some extent. If I could get each section isolated in a div with it’s own class (i.e. col1, col2, col3, col4) I could float those divs and align them just the way I want them. So, the issue isn’t whether or not I know how to do the design, I certainly do. The issue is that since these menu systems are built into the default WordPress functionality I can’t just go hard coding divs where I want them (without editing WordPress core files) and therefore I’m not having any luck. If this was straight HTML / CSS I would simply wrap each li tag I wanted with a div and position them as columns using CSS and floats most likely.

I tried using the jQuery insertBefore and insertAfter to try and insert some divs where I want them, but I didn’t realize that you can insert an opening div tag in one place and a closing div in another place, jQuery and the DOM will only let you insert the entire div (opening and closing tags) in one place.

I know there has to be a way to do this via jQuery, I just don’t know how. I’ve spent probably 5 hours playing around with no success.

Here is the code (taken straight from a view page source) for the dev site. Remember, I can’t hard code or edit any of the navigation HTML. I can only manipulate via CSS or insert divs where I need them via jQuery. I’ve pretty much exhausted the CSS route.

Thanks in advance!

**Here’s the code:**

```
<nav id="primary-navigation" class="site-navigation primary-navigation" role="navigation">
                <div class="menu-primary-menu-container"><ul id="menu-primary-menu" class="nav-menu"><li id="menu-item-33" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-33"><a href="http://devwww.interfacett.com/">Home</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-32" class="course-schedule menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-page-ancestor current-menu-ancestor current-menu-parent current_page_parent current_page_ancestor menu-item-has-children menu-item-32"><a href="http://devwww.interfacett.com/course-schedule/">Course Schedule</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-283" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-281 current_page_item menu-item-has-children menu-item-283"><a href="http://devwww.interfacett.com/course-schedule/microsoft-training/">Microsoft Training</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li id="menu-item-249" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-249"><a href="#">Windows 7</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-250" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-250"><a href="#">Windows 8</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-252" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-252"><a href="#">Windows Server 2012</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-251" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-251"><a href="#">Windows Server 2008</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-253" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-253"><a href="#">IIS</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-255" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-255"><a href="#">Exchange Server 2013</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-254" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-254"><a href="#">Exchange Server 2010</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-256" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-256"><a href="#">PowerShell</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-257" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-257"><a href="#">System Center</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-258" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-258"><a href="#">BizTalk Server 2013</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-260" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-260"><a href="#">SharePoint 2013</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-259" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-259"><a href="#">SharePoint 2010</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-261" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-261"><a href="#">SQL Server 2012 / 2008</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
        <li id="menu-item-244" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-244"><a href="#">Developer Training</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li id="menu-item-262" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-262"><a href="#">Web Development</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-263" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-263"><a href="#">Mobile App Development</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-264" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-264"><a href="#">.NET Development &#038; Visual Studio</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-265" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-265"><a href="#">Java Programming</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-266" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-266"><a href="#">Team Foundation Server 2013</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-267" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-267"><a href="#">Team Foundation Server 2012</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
        <li id="menu-item-245" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-245"><a href="#">Cisco Training</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li id="menu-item-268" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-268"><a href="#">Cisco CCNA Switching &#038; Routing</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-269" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-269"><a href="#">Cisco CCNP</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-270" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-270"><a href="#">Cisco Training &#8211; HD TelePresence</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
        <li id="menu-item-246" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-246"><a href="#">IT Security Training</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li id="menu-item-271" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-271"><a href="#">CISSP / CEH / PKI Security+</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
        <li id="menu-item-247" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-247"><a href="#">Business Training</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li id="menu-item-272" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-272"><a href="#">Project Management</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-273" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-273"><a href="#">ITIL</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-274" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-274"><a href="#">COBIT</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-275" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-275"><a href="#">Business Analysis</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-276" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-276"><a href="#">Scrum</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
        <li id="menu-item-248" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-248"><a href="#">Other Training</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li id="menu-item-277" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-277"><a href="#">CompTIA</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-278" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-278"><a href="#">Citrix</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-279" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-279"><a href="#">VMware</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-280" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-280"><a href="#">Red Hat Linux</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-31" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-31"><a href="http://devwww.interfacett.com/remotelive/">RemoteLive™</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-42" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-42"><a target="_blank" href="http://video.interfacett.com">Video Training</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-43" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-43"><a target="_blank" href="http://blogs.interfacett.com">Tech Blog</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-28" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-28"><a href="http://devwww.interfacett.com/instructors/">Instructors</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-27" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-27"><a href="http://devwww.interfacett.com/about/">About</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-26" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-26"><a href="http://devwww.interfacett.com/contact/">Contact</a></li>
    </ul></div>        </nav>
```

Comment: this might be better for wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: While you can rearrange the DOM using jQuery, this is certainly going to be more complicated, time consuming and error prone than editing the WP theme files to arrange your navigation the way you'd like - even if you have limited knowledge of php.

Comment: The problem is that this can't even be edited within the theme files. This navigation is the default WordPress navigation contained within the actual WordPress core files themselves. Perhaps I should have posted this on WordPress stack exchange though!

Comment: Have you tried positioning `li.menu-item-32>ul>li` elements?

Comment: I haven't tried positioning ul.nav-menu>li elements yet. I'll play around with it. I've been racking my brain for hours on this, so perhaps I just need to take a break and then come back to it.

Comment: @DigitalSky - you might want to check out [this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Appearance_Menus_SubPanel) and [this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu)